# Add 2 different versions of same package in NuGet

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to have 2 different versions of the same NuGet package (in my case it's jQuery 1.10.1 & 2.0.2) within same project?

If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: From a JS reference perspective this could really screw things up

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: I was planning to add these 2 NuGet packages side-by-side so as to load one file on a Page depending on browser being IE8 or not... since I heard that IE8 support is removed in jquery 2.0.2.

Comment: Your need/approach is sound, it is just that the `NuGet` mechanism is not geared towards solving your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802007/using-two-different-versions-of-same-the-nuget-package

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Check out NuGet issue [Allow side-by-side versions of jQuery (and others)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180102132709/http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/964). It was closed by Phil Haack (NuGet contributor) with message "won't fix".

The recommended workaround by Phil Haack is "You've hit the boundaries of NuGet. Just reference one of them using a CDN or manually add the script files."

Comment: i was exactly going through the same Post... looks like that option is not available...

Comment: Too bad it's not possible yet. Hope someday it'll make it to reality.