# Replace component inside existing application with specific NuGet without disrupting application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, nopcommerce

I have an existing MVC ASP.NET application that needs a NopCommerce (ASP.NET eCommerce platform) plugin replaced but said plugin uses a different version of AutoFac than the rest of the application. I do not know how to replace said plugin without bricking the entire application.

---

I've tried this a couple times and I get the same error where it says it cannot find the version of AutoFac I want to include, 4.6.2. First time I just put the compiled plugin in the new location and it broke (sorta expected) then I included the new AutoFac in the same directory and that broke. At some point in the future we are expecting to get all NuGet packages in line but owing to some poor development decisions I'm working to correct we're not ready for that yet. What can I do in the meantime?

Comment: Kinda similar question but not exactly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802007/using-two-different-versions-of-same-the-nuget-package) . Depending how much control you have over the packages used.

Comment: I'm looking at taking a stab at option three on that provided link. Will update after maintenance period.