# How to resolve a version issue between packages

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

We have an old framework application in need of package updates. The project has a dependency on `System.ComponentModel.Annotations`. The most recent version is "5.0.0.0".

This is the content of the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

One of the other packages, over which I have no control, uses version "4.2.0.0" of the annotations package. The auto generated binding redirects do not solve this. There are several questions about binding redirects, but none seem address my situation.

How do I modify my project file to make this work, or do I need something altogether different?

Comment: Why don't you install `4.2.0`?

Comment: @FortyTwo Some parts do need the newer version.

Comment: I would question the approach here, because either you build your project with the capabilities of `4.2.0` or somehow update the version in your referenced project. If neither is possible and you need both the versions then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802007/using-two-different-versions-of-the-same-nuget-package) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the followning binding redirect to the **app.config** solves the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```