# Install two versions of a package with Nuget

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to find out if there is any way to install two versions of a NuGet package?

The reason is exceptionally limited, but we install the latest version of the `1x` build of jQuery as well as whatever the most recent version is. Based on that we will see if the latest version is loaded correctly. If it's not we add in a script tag that references the `1x` build. This is mainly for backward compatibility.

So, is this possible? Currently, we just use NuGet to get the latest version and then download the `1x` build from jQuery directly.

Comment: http://www.rajapet.com/2014/03/bundling-jquery-2-x-and-jquery-1-x-in-asp-net-mvc-and-staying-nuget-fresh.html

Comment: @Hackerman This process is exceedingly similar to the process that we already use. However, this doesn't answer the question of how to use NuGet to install two versions. It instead shows you how to install an update without NuGet deleting the old version. Which is similar, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555126/can-we-add-2-different-versions-of-same-package-in-nuget