# Use two different versions of the same nuget in one project to build two different apps?

Tags: c#, f#, nuget, csproj, fsproj

I want to build my app once using the latest and greatest version of the main nuget package.
But due to [an unresolved error](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9064) I also need to build it with a lower version of the same nuget package for the hosted use case.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555126/can-we-add-2-different-versions-of-same-package-in-nuget) I would think it is not possible in one project? Do I need to split it into several projects?
I am using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.
The actual code does not change when switching packages. (The APIs I use from the nuget stay the same.)

**Edit:**
At the moment I am just changing one number in the nuget reference and build again two have both version, Can this be automated with some build infrastructue?

**Edit2**: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/GoswinR/status/1263023244753461249) suggest its possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible or it's not worth the effort. Use a lower version of the same NuGet or fix the bug. Maybe it would be possible by dynamically loading the DLL like `Assembly.LoadFile("mylibv1.dll")`, `Assembly.LoadFile("mylibv2.dll")` but it sounds more complicated than just using a lower version or fixing the bug. Otherwise how will the application know which FSharp.Core.dll it needs to load and use?